# How to import data from Excel to PL/SQL Developer

Tags: excel, oracle, plsqldeveloper

I need to compare data from tables in Oracle with data from tables in excel, how can I import data from excel. How can I import data from excel to test table in oracle pl/sql dev?

Comment: In the title you write you are using "PL/SQL Developer" but in the body you say "oracle pl/sql dev"; the problem with this is that "PL/SQL Developer" is a third-party client application developed by Allround-Automations and is nothing to do with Oracle whereas Oracle's client application is called "SQL Developer" (No "PL/" in the name). Which are you using as there will be different solutions for each client application?

Comment: I sometimes add a column in excel containing a formula that compose an `INSERT` statement from the values of that row. This way I just need to copy and paste the whole column into sqlplus, sqldeveloper or any other tool, which allows to run sql-scripts.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two options:

**Option I:**

- Create test table with no. of columns and data type matching with excel data.
- Open the test table in PL/SQL developer in edit mode. You can do this by selecting rowid in SELECT statement or writing the SELECT with 'for update'. For example:

```sql
SELECT t.*, t.rowid FROM test t;
OR
SELECT t.* FROM test t for update;
```

- Click on the lock ICON to keep it in pressed status for opening the fetched rows for editing.
- Now copy the data range from excel and in PL/SQL developers SQL result grid, select the empty column and paste the copied data.
  (Note: you would need to add one empty column in the beginning of your first data column and include that blank column as well while copying data. This blank column is a placeholder for the serial no. column in PL/SQL developer's result grid. Otherwise your first data column will be eaten up by the serial no. column of result grid. :-) ).
- Click on green tick to commit the data to database.

**Option II:**
In excel you can compose INSERT query referencing data cells with help of Excel's concatenation (using & ) and execute all INSERT in PL/SQL developer.

Answer (score 1):

if you have 0ver 100 k data or upper maybe almost a million data , i suggest to change data type of your excel to csv file,then now your going to import to pl/sql : 1. go to tools and choose text importer
2. then browse csv file and upload (data from textfile)
3. go to next tab and choose user and your table (data to oracle)
4. make sure your field suitable with your csv data
5. then import, if you find "ora" error make sure your varchar fit the data